# Why does DTD validation fail when optional child element is omitted?

Tags: xml, xml-validation, dtd

The XML document has embedded DTD declaration and it fails.

Here is DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE movieList [

<!ELEMENT movieList (movie+)>
<!ELEMENT movie (title+, rating+, runTime+, genreList*, dateReleased+, 
          country+, review+, description+, director+)>

<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT rating (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT runTime (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT genreList (genre+)>
<!ELEMENT genre (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT dateReleased (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT country (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT review (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT director (#PCDATA)>
]>
```

And here are XML elements:

```
<movieList>
<movie>
    <title>Jaws</title>
    <rating>PG</rating>
    <runTime>124 minutes</runTime>
    <genreList>
        <genre>Adventure</genre>
        <genre>Thriller</genre>
    </genreList>
    <dateReleased>20 June 1975</dateReleased>
    <country>USA</country>
    <review>8</review>
    <description>When a gigantic great white shark begins to menace 
    the small island community of Amity, a police chief, a marine 
    scientist and grizzled fisherman set out to stop it.</description>
    <director>Steven Spielberg</director>
</movie>

<movie>
    <title>The Good, the Bad and the Ugly</title>
    <rating>NR</rating>
    <runTime>161 minutes</runTime>
        <genre>Western</genre>
    <dateReleased>23 December 1966</dateReleased>
    <country>Italy</country>
    <review>9</review>
    <description>A bounty hunting scam joins two men in an uneasy 
    alliance against a third in a race to find a fortune in gold buried 
    in a remote cemetery.</description>
    <director>Sergio Leone</director>
</movie>
</movieList>
```

It fails where I have only one `genre` and not wrapped the elements with `genreList`. It should work because in the `movie` element declaration I have `genreList*` which means, the `genreList` will appear 0 or more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You explain your results and your expectations very well.

You're right that `genreList*` means that `genreList` may be absent.  However, if `genreList` is absent, its children cannot be present.  The content model for `movie` has no provision for `genre` without `genreList`, thus your XML is invalid per the DTD, as reported correctly.

Comment: always think of XML in terms of trees: `genreList*` means that zero to many `genreList` trees can occur. `genre` then is part of that tree. if there is no `genreList`, there can be no `genre`.

Comment: @OP To put it another way, your content model for `movie` specifies exactly what children `movie` is allowed to have, and that list does not include `genre`. In that sense, it doesn't matter if `genreList` or any other element have `genre` in their content model... it only matters that `movie` doesn't.